# Unable to override MockStore

Tags: angular, ngrx

I used provideMockStore for unit testing more than one selector. I need to override the MockStore for one of the test cases. Code is as follows. It is not overriding the store. I have seen documentation there it is mentioned that mockStore = TestBed.inject(MockStore). It throws error that reads "Property 'inject' doesn't exist on type 'TestBedStatic'
"@angular/cli": "~8.2.1",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
        "@ngrx/effects": "^8.2.0",
        "@ngrx/entity": "^8.2.0",
        "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.2.0",
        "@ngrx/schematics": "^8.2.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "^8.2.0",

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                RegisteredOwnerContainerComponent,
                RegisteredOwnerComponent,
                AddVehicleTitleComponent,
                SidePanelContentComponent,
                ExplanationComponent
            ],
            imports: [
                FlexLayoutModule,
                FormsModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                MaterialModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
                LoggerModule.forRoot({ level: NgxLoggerLevel.INFO, disableConsoleLogging: false })
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivateRoute },
                { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter },
                {
                    provide: EndorsementStateService,
                    useValue: {
                        navigateToNextStep: jasmine.createSpy('navigateToNextStep')
                    }
                },
                provideMockStore({
                    selectors: [
                        { selector: currentPolicySelector, value: currentPolicy },
                        { selector: currentVehicleSelector, value: currentVehicle }
                    ],
                }),
                CookieService
            ],
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegisteredOwnerContainerComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        mockedStore = TestBed.get(Store);
        mockService = TestBed.get(EndorsementStateService);

        // mockedStore.select = jasmine.createSpy('select');
    }));

it('should return empty driver array if no PNI and SNI exist', fakeAsync(() => {
        mockedStore.overrideSelector(currentPolicySelector, currentPolicyWithoutPNIAndWithoutSNI);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TestBed.inject` is an angular 9 function.

For angular 8, use `TestBed.get`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had tried mockedStore = TestBed.get(MockStore);  But got an error: NullInjectorError: No provider for MockStore!

Comment: You can't get the `MockStore` from `TestBed` in v8 (this is a bug). You will have to get the Store and cast it to MockStore. TestBed.get(Store) as Mockstore

Comment: @timdeschryver is that issue tracked anywhere?

Comment: @ChrisPaton
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2468